# How to order a list of vectors based on the order of values contained within [in R]

Tags: r

I have the following object:

```
L <- list(4, 7, c(3, 1), c(1, 2), c(5, 6))
> L
[[1]]
[1] 4

[[2]]
[1] 7

[[3]]
[1] 3 1

[[4]]
[1] 1 2

[[5]]
[1] 5 6
```

which I would like to reorder based on the appearance of each value, such that those vectors containing `1` come first, and the vector `1,2` comes before `1,3`. My desired result would be:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 3 1

[[3]]
[1] 4

[[4]]
[1] 5 6

[[5]]
[1] 7
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

#### Edit:

Here is a more complicated case:

```
L <- list(7, c(9, 20), c(2, 3), c(10, 17), c(1, 12, 14), c(1, 3, 5, 
12), c(8, 9, 18, 19), c(6, 11, 15, 16, 17), c(4, 6, 11, 13, 15, 
16))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit more involved, but I believe it will work

```
ml<-max(sapply(L, length))
reord<-do.call(order, data.frame(
    do.call(rbind, 
        lapply(L, function(x) c(sort(x), rep.int(0, ml-length(x))))
    )
))
L[reord]
```

Comment: Very nice - this seems to work. I've tried it on some more complicated cases as well. I'll add one of these to the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
L[order(sapply(L,function(x)paste0(sort(x),collapse=".")))]
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 3 1
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 4
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 5 6
#
# [[5]]
# [1] 7
```

This will work for integers of up to n digits:

```
L <- list(4, 7, c(3, 1), c(20, 10), c(5, 6))
library(stringr)
n <- 5
L[order(sapply(L,function(x)paste0(str_pad(sort(x),n,pad="0"),collapse=".")))]
```

Comment: I'm speechless - never thought `order` could handle text strings like that.

Comment: This seems to fail with the case `L <- list(4, 7, c(3, 1), c(10, 2), c(5, 6))`. It puts `c(10,2)` second rather than last.

Comment: It should be 2nd because of the `2`.

Comment: @Marcinthebox Ok. I guess i miss understood the original intent, but i still believe it fails with `L <- list(4, 7, c(3, 1), c(20, 10), c(5, 6))`

Comment: @MrFlick - Yes, in that case it would fail. Just to be clear - my list would only contain sequential integers, but I guess a general solution would be better.

Comment: @Marcinthebox even if you only use sequential integers, it fails with `L <- list(4, 7, c(3, 1), c(20, 19), c(5, 6))`

Answer (score 2):

```
L[sort(sapply(L, '[[', 1), index.return = T)$ix]
```

Comment: If i understand the question correctly, I believe this will fail with `L <- list(4, 7, c(3, 10), c(3, 2), c(5, 6))`. The `c(3,2)` element should come first, not the `c(3,10)` element.

Comment: Ah. I assumed that it was sorted by the first element.